# How to define color range of particular color from RGB/CMYK/Hexcode model?

Tags: colors, color-scheme, color-space

I am trying to find a segment in color wheel which is dedicated to particular color only (For example, red or green or black or violet).

So far, i have tried following:

- I used 12 colors and 20 shades of each color to narrow down a color range(https://digitalsynopsis.com/design/color-thesaurus-correct-names-of-shades/). But, i was clearly not able to define the range of particular color because i have not found any pattern which could say when i will enter into differen color segment.
- For example, to define black color, what digit should be the minimum and maximum in RGB or any other module?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming

Comment: It is related to programming. Here is How: I am trying to find a logic here which could help me build a code or technique to convert it into code. Do you have some idea on coding then please feel free to share!

Comment: Please share your attempts - you should at least try something and then we can help you improve that logic

Comment: Right now, I have taken logical approach by considering 240 colors. Here is what i am doing:

- Getting RGB value of 240 colors
- Calculating the MEAN (Average) of three R, G and B value
- To decide about which color is falling into above 240 colors, i am comparing the mean the color (X) with the mean of 240 colors
- Assigning the color (X) one color from the 240 set (based on the nearest mean)

That is what i have done so far. It is fulfilling the concept upto some limits but not in all cases.

Comment: Please add all your attempts to the question itself by editing it, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain which parts are not covered by this

Comment: Black is not in colour wheels. Colour wheels are also not "well" defined. there are many possible way. CMYK is nearly always a wrong colour space to work. In any case, you are looking for HSL/HSV colour space. Check how to convert, then it should be easy to partition.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for your suggestion. Yes, black and white are not directly available in the color wheel. Based on my exploration i feel the same that color wheel has particular pattern of how all the colors has been defined (Not properly implemented). If you have come across any HSL/HSV reference which could help in this situation then please do share. (In terms of logic or code.)

Comment: The names of your links are wrong. For one: there is no well established names, Second: it seems that the author checked name of real objects, without much thinking (e.g. "rose" for the "red rose". Rose usually (in nature) are not red, for this reason we have "red rose"). BTW there is also a different "rose" in pink part. "Wine" looks like bottle wine, and not usual "wine" colour. Violet is wrong,... My proposal is to build a "wheel" of colours, discreate, equidistant, and give a name. e.g. 8 hues x 8 variation (4 shades, 4 tints). xkcd and TheMathGuy did some experiment on names vs colours.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Till now, i have used those colors without assigning any name in the system. System considers those name as x1, x2 ...etc.. But, now for color range i have to identify the name or section of particular color from the wheel to produce precise result. In case if you have link with explanation for reference you have shared then please do share. 

Do you think P5.js library could be useful to define color range?